# MySQL: Simple LIKE statement not matching pattern as expected

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using AJAX to execute a mysql LIKE query and display the result set data using html.

It seems that the results returned from the query always use whatever is stored in the `searchword` variable minus the last character and I do not know why.

**MySQL:** `("SELECT * FROM products WHERE prod_name LIKE '".$searchword."%'")`

var_dump when searchword var contains 'bab' = `string(49) "SELECT * FROM products WHERE prod_name LIKE 'ba%'"`

**JQuery/ AJAX:**

```
function search(searchword) {      
    $('.smart-suggestions').load('invoice-get-data.php?searchword=' + searchword); 
}
```

**Markup**

```
<input onKeyPress="search(this.value)" type="text" class="prod-name-input"/>
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code in invoice-get-data.php?

Comment: You've verified that `$searchword` contains "bab" before the query is executed? (In other words, the full keyword is getting to the PHP code, and it's only in the query that it's getting truncated?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that onkeypress fires before the value of the text field gets updated.  This is why you're seeing the one character delay.  To fix this, you can use **onkeyup** instead.

```
<input onKeyUp="search(this.value)" type="text" class="prod-name-input"/>
```